# Changing the input and output directory in Vite

Tags: vite

I am using Vite (https://vitejs.dev/) for a static multipage site.
This is the default project folder structure after the build command.

```
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ dist/
│  ├─ assets/
│  ├─ index.html
├─ index.html
├─ main.js
├─ style.scss
├─ package.json
```

But I want to make this a multipage site and change the input and output directory for a better organizable way like this

```
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ package.json
├─ src/
│  ├─ about.html
│  ├─ index.html
│  ├─ main.js
│  ├─ style.scss
├─ dist/
│  ├─ assets/
│  ├─ about.html
│  ├─ index.html
```

Basically, it should take the `src` as an input folder and output `dist` as a child of the `my-app`. When I try to do this it shows errors, then I change the scripts of the `package.json` into this

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite src",
    "build": "vite build src",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
```

This way the `dev`command works fine. But the 'build' command makes the dist folder inside the `src` folder and does not generate other HTML files except `index.html`.

Now how can I fix this? Any suggestion?

Comment: If you want to know the reason of this behavior (`dist` folder inside `src` instead of the project `root` folder), you can read this anser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69540835/774432

Comment: the fact that vite works out of the box so well that when trying to make a static multipage site the first thing you need to configure is the outdir is amazing! imagine your webpack config before you got to this question lol

Answer (score 104):

Create a `vite.config.js` file and define your project root and output directory as such:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: 'src',
  build: {
    outDir: '../dist'
  }
}
```

For more info, checkout [config](https://vitejs.dev/config/#build-outdir).

Comment: You also need to set `build.emptyOutDir` to `true`.

Comment: See DrSiemer answer. The missing point here is that the vite.config.js file needs to be in the src folder, otherwise even with the configs set properly, it won't output the dist folder outside of the src folder.

Answer (score 20):

For [**multipage apps**](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app) you need to specify each entry point.

To dynamically specify all `.html` files in `src/` directory as the entry points you can set up your `vite.config.js` like this:

```js
import path from "path";
import glob from "glob";

export default {
  root: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  build: {
    outDir: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    rollupOptions: {
      input: glob.sync(path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "*.html")),
    },
  },
};
```

Make sure to install [**`glob`**](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) like this

```bash
npm install glob -D
```

Comment: For other vite noobs like me, glob refers to an external npm package [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) and you need to install it as a dev dependency first.

Comment: This is the only answer I was looking for since the release of Vite. I just wanted to use Vanilla HTML with Vite just for the live preview. But multiple HTML files makes it difficult to implement. This answer solved my year long mystery. Thanks man!

Comment: Do you know how to specify the chunk names? If each of your different html pages shares any code/components how can you get a duplicated chunk file for each html page or how can you preset what the chunk name should be? I'm trying to make each page of the multi page app independent, but I can't figure out the naming nomenclature. Thanks.

Comment: Because I have nested paths I needed to modify glob to the following: `input: glob.sync(path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "**/*.html"))`

Answer (score 15):

Make sure you add vite.config.js *inside* your Vite root directory (src).

```js
    module.exports = defineConfig({
      base: '',
      root: 'src',
      build: {
        outDir: '../dist'
      }
    });
```

Don't forget to update your package scripts. You'll need to add the `--emptyOutDir` flag if you want the same behavior as in the default project structure (clear output folder before building).

```js
    "scripts": {
      "dev": "vite src",
      "build": "vite build src --emptyOutDir",
    }
```

Comment: It should be noted that 'emptyOutDir' is a build option as well and can be used instead of the cli flag.  `build: { outDir: '../dist', emptyOutDir: true }`

Comment: The most important step is what you said: the vite.config.js file MUST be in the src folder. Otherwise, I tried everything  and it won't work.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use defineConfig in your vite.config.ts you can use it like this:

```js
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
    import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh'
    import eslintPlugin from 'vite-plugin-eslint'
    
    // https://vitejs.dev/config/
    export default defineConfig({
        plugins: [reactRefresh(), eslintPlugin({ cache: false })],
        root: 'src',
        build: {
            outDir: '../dist'
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 7):

You can set up your vite.config.js like this:

```js
import path from 'path'

export default {
  root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  build: {
    outDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        index: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html'),
        about: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/about.html')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `vite.config.js` file and specify it's location in your `package.json` scripts using the `--config` flag:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --config ./config/vite.config.js",
    "build": "vite build --config ./config/vite.config.js
    "preview": "vite preview --config ./config/vite.config.js"
  },
```

Inside your vite config file include the following:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  root: 'src',
  build: {
    outDir: '../dist',
    emptyOutDir: true,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

another example, on my vite project

```
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ dist/
│  ├─ registerSW.js
│  ├─ index.html
├─ index.html
├─ index.ts
├─ style.css
├─ vite.config.ts
├─ index.ts
├─ package.json
```

Depending on the structure project  as above, the URL was https://domain_name.com/my-app/dist/. The default "index.html" file   is located in "dist" folder. How to display it without subfolder in URL ?  I mean how to convert
from https://domain_name.com/my-app/dist/ to just https://domain_name.com/

My solution ^^ here we have slight changes in the configuration file.                                                            `Pay attention, if you set emptyOutDir to true, that will remove all files on your server`

```
export default defineConfig({
  base: "./",
  root:"../my-app",
  build: {
    emptyOutDir: **false**, //Pay attention !
    outDir: '../',
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        assetFileNames: "[name].[ext]",
        chunkFileNames: "[name].[ext]",
        entryFileNames: "[name].js",
      },
    },
  },
```

The structure project will be like this

```
    ├─ my-app/
    │  ├─ node_modules/
    │  ├─ index.html
    │  ├─ index.ts
    │  ├─ style.css
    │  ├─ vite.config.ts
    │  ├─ index.ts
    │  ├─ package.json
    ├─ registerSW.js
    ├─ index.html
```