# Vite - Static Files Are Not Copying

Tags: vue.js, vite

I have a Vue.js app that relies on [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/). In this app, I have two static files that I need to copy to my `dist` directory: `favicon.ico` and `manifest.json`. My `vite.config.js` file looks like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(({command, mode }) => {
  return {
    assetsDir: 'res',
    plugins: [vue()],
    publicDir: 'dist',
    root: 'src',
    build: {
      emptyOutDir: true,
      outDir: '../dist'
    }
  }
});
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
/
  /dist
  /src
    /assets
      favicon.ico
      manifest.json
    /res
      /css
        theme.css
    App.vue
    main.js
    index.html
  package.json
  README.md
  vite.config.js
```

When I compile my program using `npm run build`, I can see a file named `index.html` that gets created in the `dist` directory. However, I have been unsuccessful in getting the `favicon.ico` and `manifest.json` file copied to the `dist` directory, which is what I need. I tried adding `publicDir: 'assets'` to the `build` options. However, that didn't work. I also tried creating a `public` directory under the `src` directory in an effort to follow along with [this documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory). However, that did not move the files to the directory. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Reason**: The public (vite option) directory is relative to your root (vite option) directory.

So, as you specified `root: 'src'` and `publicDir: 'dist'` then your `public` dir is `./src/dist`

Illustration of the folder tree based on your `vite.config.js` :

[image]

*More information below*

---

If you have assets that are :

- Never referenced in source code (e.g. favicon.ico)
- Must retain the exact same file name (without hashing)
- ...or you simply don't want to have to import an asset first just to get its URL

Then the doc say:

> You can place the asset in a special `public` directory under your
> project root. Assets in this directory will be served at root path `/`
> during dev, and copied to the root of the dist directory as-is.

This mean that if you simply place the `favicon.ico` under the `/public` dir it will be copied to the `dist` dir after build.

The note above **is true if you have a vanilla** `vite` config, but if you change the `publicDir` options of `vite` config then read below after the illustration.

[image]

`favicon.ico` copied in `dist` after `vite build`

---

If you set a custom `publicDir` :

As said on the top of this answer, the `public` *(vite option)* directory is relative to your `root` *(vite option)* directory.

So, if for example you set `root: './src'` and set `publicDir: 'mypublic'` **then the public dir will be**  `./src/mypublic`.

Comment: I added a `public` directory under the `src` directory and at the same level as the `src` directory. Still, the contents of the `public` directory are _not_ copied to the `dist` directory. I suspect it has something to do with either the `assetsDir` value or `root` value, but I haven't confirmed. Regardless, `favicon.ico` and `manifest.json` are not getting copied to the `dist` directory.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I have been digging through Vite's documentation forever looking for this information and either its not there anymore or I'm just bad at reading