Vite places main.js in different folder
I have a Vite project. I placed main.js in different folder

I set rollupOptions in vite.config.js

But when I input "npm run dev" in Vite CLI and opened URL in browser, there still appeared an error

[Vite] Pre-transform error: Failed to load url /src/main.js (resolved id: /src/main.js). Does the file exist?
I obviously set entry for main.js. Why does Vite still use default url "/src/main.js"? It seems that my effort doesn't work. How to configure vite for my main.js?

does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66863200/changing-the-input-and-output-directory-in-vite

This question is similar to: Changing the input and output directory in Vite. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please [edit] your question to convert images into text, and use a [code block] for any code you have. Readers can then search the text or run the code to reproduce your issue.

Check if index.html includes /src/main.js
