Understanding Svelte final library size
EDIT (findings): I tried again after removing all references to Inertia, and only imported my example page in main.js (no other pages), and the result is the same: this example page component still weighs 62KB (unminified and uncompressed) according to the visualizer, whereas the corresponding MainPage.svelte file only weighs 5KB on the filesystem. It really feels like the visualizer is giving the size after imported stuff was incorporated in the file, even though it still displays said imported stuff alongside the svelte component in their own rectangles.
EDIT (findings): after trying from scratch with StackBlitz, I discovered that just using router from @inertiajs/svelte immediately adds 110KB to the final file (minified, uncompressed).
I have a tiny (3 pages: login + 2 other pages) app in Svelte + Inertia.
When in dev mode, one of my page components weighs 5KB. But when built, rollup-plugin-visualizer gives me 62KB for that same component (unminified, that is), and the total weight of my final JS file (building in "library mode") is 250KB... For just 3 tiny pages. It shouldn't be more than like 50KB.
The final file seems to include a few node modules (svelte for 31KB, inertia for 30KB, axios for 95KB, qs for 30KB, object-inspect for 19KB, etc.), which account for 250KB total (unminified), and my app files themselves account for a whopping 350KB unminified (three times what they actually weigh in the filesystem, including comments etc.: 120KB)
I can't understand how that can be. Each file is represented in its own rectangle, so it's not like rollup-plugin-visualizer is resolving imports and including them in the displayed size for each component or something. So, how can a single file go from 5KB (actual size) to 62KB ("rollup size", according to the visualizer)?
I have always been a fan of using tiny libs for specific needs in order to actively reduce the resulting apps sizes to the max (having slow mobile connections in mind), but now that I am trying Svelte (that I really love!!) I am disappointed with the final size for such a microscopic app, and I'd like to reduce it like to 50KB or something.
Any ideas? I'd like to stick to Svelte if possible. If I can't, then maybe there is another frontend framework that would be really tiny?
My vite options, if necessary:
build: {
    outDir: '../server/dist', // https://stackoverflow.com/a/66867648/1971322
    emptyOutDir: false,
    lib: {
        entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main.js'),
        name: 'xyz', // This parameter is mandatory, but won't even be used...
    },
    rollupOptions: {
        output: {
            entryFileNames: `js/[name].js`,
            chunkFileNames: `js/[name].js`,
            assetFileNames: `js/[name].[ext]`
        }
    }
}


The size should be nowhere near that. If you compile the Svelte + Vite template on StackBlitz, the JS for the single component amounts to 8.08 kB (gzipped: 3.64 kB). Did you re-export svelte or use imports that cannot be tree-shaken? (Your file will obviously "grow" if you use libraries and those are bundled in, but Svelte should usually not contribute much there.)

If you don't want a library to be bundled you have to make it external.

@brunnerh I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I am not re-exporting svelte. I'm just importing svelte and inertia like normal (the only svelte module I am actively importing is the store). I'm even importing specific JS files in inertia (which is ugly) in order to skip the weight added by the useForm (which is roughly 30KB minified, used by lodash) that is included in the @inertia/svelte/index file. I'll try to replicate on StackBlitz and provide more info here.

@brunnerh which StackBlitz are you using to get this 8KB file? I tried this one and it results in a 110KB bundle.

The template I used is in: New Project > Frontend > Svelte (JavaScript). Also, what you linked to compiles to a 48.1 kB bundle (npm run build && ls -l -h public/build/bundle.js).

@brunnerh I have content-length: 115925 but maybe it's not tree-shaken yet. If I specifically build, yes I have 49288 on filesystem, but it's still not 8KB, and it's an even tinier app than mine ; also, if I create a new blank Svelte app and do import {router} from '@inertiajs/svelte' and then if (router) console.log('router') to prevent tree-shaking, then I go from 5KB to 116KB. Maybe it's just Inertia that is broken... But that wouldn't explain why my Svelte component shows as 62KB when it actually weighs 5KB on filesystem. After trying again without inertia, my component still is 62KB...

How is it surprising that the size goes up when you import libraries? A lot of libraries add a significant amount of code, if that gets bundled with the component such size increases are expected. If you can create a minimal reproduction where there is a significant size increase without library imports, that would be unusual and something to look into. Unless you can provide this, there probably is not much else to be done here.

@brunnerh my question is specifically about Svelte+Inertia (it got removed from my question's title by a moderator), and I already proved with a minimal reproduction that just including Inertia's router adds 110KB (minified) to the resulting file, which is insanely high. So yeah the optim might be on the Inertia's side, not Svelte, but the resulting file is still unexpectedly too heavy. Thanks anyway for your input

You provided part of one config, that is not a valid reproduction.

(Also, don't measure unminified size, it's a mostly useless metric that nobody uses, so if you e.g. check sizes of libraries elsewhere, it will not be listed.)
